# mdadm RAID monitoring on Debian

Tags: debian, monitoring, mdadm

I tested mdadm software RAID on a Debian 9 virtual machine.  I migrated to RAID myself (i.e. didn't rely on the installer).

It works nicely, and `dpkg-reconfigure mdadm` even offered to set up monthly scrubs and email alerts.  I can see this runs `/sbin/mdadm --monitor --scan`.  However `mail -u root` shows no mail after booting with only one device.

What is the simplest way to ensure a notification is generated when booting in degraded mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `dpkg-reconfigure mdadm` defaults to sending mail to `root`, Debian's Mail Delivery Agent no longer supports sending mail to `root`.  If you left everything as default, you need to use `mail -u mail` instead.  The best approach is to make sure all `root` mail is directed somewhere it will be read - you can use your normal user for this.  `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` will prompt for such a user (it recommends against just leaving the default forward to `mail`).